# Can I run custom middleware after authentication but before ClaimsTransformation.cs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

Can I run custom middleware after authentication but before ClaimsTransformation.cs?

ClaimsTransformation uses a token to make an external API call to get some information on the logged in user. I want to pass the OpenId connect token instead, and thus, need that token before the API call is made.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the OpenId connect token instead? id-token or access-token?

The id-token is never allowed to supposed to be passed to any API, it is only meant for the client who initially received it and is typically only used to create the local user session.

One idea is to add a custom middleware between the Authentication and Authorization middleware to manipulate the user.